# Controlling LEDs with I2C

Tags: led, circuit-design, i2c, gpio

I'm trying to connect about 4 LEDs to an MCU (SAMD21G) to power on when specific things happen, but all the pins are being used.

I was thinking that I could connect some kind of LED strip through I2C to the MCU since I can connect multiple devices to a single I2C line, but I couldn't find any LED strip like that.

Should I connect the LEDs to another IC that communicates over I2C with the MCU, or is there another way to go about this, and what are the downsides of connecting the LEDs like that?

Comment: Can your MCU I2C port be programmed to SPI? SPI can easily emulate the pulses required for *individually addressable LEDs*. Besides strips, they are also available as discrete LEDs. Some require 12V, but others are 5V.

Comment: Yea, but the SPI pins are already being used by other things so I am not able to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is an I2C GPIO expander IC.

If you're driving LEDs from one, make sure you check the maximum current allowed per pin, as well as the total maximum current for the device. If you need more current than the GPIO expander IC can handle, you can add transistors (MOSFETs or BJTs) to drive the LEDs.

Comment: Another choice might be a LED-specific driver chip as they usually have more convenient current-limiting and higher voltage and/or current handling capability.

Comment: Yea that sounds like what I need thank you. I have a follow up question, since I already have something connected to my I2C line and I want it directly connected just in case the GPIO expander IC fails or something, is it okay to connect the expander IC on the same line as something else or do I have to connect the expander IC directly to the I2C line and then connected everything else through it?

Comment: @vir Yup, also a good suggestion. Might require a smidge more understanding to get right, but if dimming is required it's a better approach.

Comment: Yea, I don't really need dimming I just want the LEDs to turn on or off, would you still recommend LED driver IC or is it not needed?

Comment: @MostafaIbrahim Both devices should go on the same I2C bus. An LED driver IC is not required; a GPIO expander will work as long as you pay attention to the maximum current source and sink specifications in the datasheet, or add transistors to drive the LEDs.

Comment: Also make sure whichever chip you choose doesn't have the same address as anything else on your bus (and runs at the same voltage).  Most chips will have one or two address pins that you use to set the I2C address, but some smaller ones just have one address that can't be changed.

Comment: @vir Oh okay great, was worried about that. So I can just leave whatever is connected on the same bus the same and just change the chip address.

Comment: Yes, there will be a table in the datasheet that will tell you which configuration of pins pulled high and/or low will result in which address.